# Spring boot web application does not have cache-control header

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, cache-control

I am using a Spring boot application and there is a requirement to enable security by disabling the caching between the web-pages.
As I understand,  by default, Spring Security sets specific cache-control header values for us, without us having to configure anything.

But for my web application, the following response headers are not present.
Cache-Control", "no-store"
Pragma", "no-cache"
Expires", "0"
I have tried setting them using an interceptor(implementing HandlerInterceptor) and adding the following code in the preHandle, postHandle and afterCompletionMethod.

```
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); // HTTP 1.1.
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
```

Although the control comes to these methods and the header is set, when I inspect the web-browser, I don't see these headers.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

There are different types of setting the header.

I would suggest to set it either with a filter or the configuration.

**Configuration**

By default spring-boot sets security headers. With the .defaultsDisabled() you disable them and can selective activate the wanted headers.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    // ...
    .headers()
        // do not use any default headers unless explicitly listed
        .defaultsDisabled()
        .cacheControl();
}
}
```

Will set the header to following settings:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

For more detail of the configuration here is the doc. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/headers.html

Alternative you can yous a filter.

**Filter**

```
@WebFilter("/filter-response-header/*")
public class AddResponseHeaderFilter implements Filter {
 
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpServletResponse.setHeader(
          "Cache-Control", "no-store");
httpServletResponse.setHeader(
              "Pragma", "no-cache");
httpServletResponse.setHeader(
              "Expires", "0");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

**For a single response**

HttpServletResponse:

```
HttpServletResponse response
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.addHeader("Expires", "0");
```

for more have a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-header